# Shared and exclusive named lock for python

Tags: python, synchronization, locking

I need to synchronize python threads and processes (not necessary related with each other) with named lock (file lock for example). Preferably it should be readers-writer lock. I have tried fcntl.flock (it have both exclusive and shared lock acquisition) but it does not provide desired level of locking - [Does python's fcntl.flock function provide thread level locking of file access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899435/does-pythons-fcntl-flock-function-provide-thread-level-locking-of-file-access)

My solution so far is to use [lockfile](http://packages.python.org/lockfile/lockfile.html) with memcached (or mmap'ed locked file). Lockfile will synchronize access and memcached will count readers/writers.

Are there any better/faster solutions? Do you know any project which already solves this problem?

Comment: I'd be interested in any solution as well.

Comment: Try [ilock](https://github.com/symonsoft/ilock) library

Answer (score 2):

Here is a link http://semanchuk.com/philip/ with libraries implementing posix and system V semaphores. You can use one of those. Beware though that in a situation when process holding semaphore dies without releasing it - all other get stucked. If you afraid of this - you can use System V Semaphores with UNDO but they are a little slower. Also if you are happen to use System V shared memory primitives - remember that they live in kernel and keep living after process termination - you have to explicitly remove them from system.

If you are not afraid of dying processes and deadlock of whole system and processes are related - you could use python's Semaphores (they are posix named semaphores.)

The page you linked as related question (fcntl) does not saying that fcntl is not suitable for  inter thread locking. It is saying that fcntl cares about fds. So you can use fcntl for inter-process and inter-thread locking as long as you open locking file and get new fd for each lock instance.

You could also use a combination of fcntl for inter-process and python's semaphore for inter-thread locking.

And finally: rethink your architecture. Locking is generally bad. Delegate resource to a process that will take care of it without locking. It will be much more simplier to maintain. Believe me.